# Problem 1 - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-cache

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm create one project...

```
 php composer.phar create-project -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application zf3-helloworld 
 cd zf3-helloworld/
 cp composer.phar zf3-helloworld/
 cd zf3-helloworld/

 php composer.phar update
```

I'm use PHP7.2

I installed several packages without problems, however try to install the package zendframework / zend-cache, I get the error:

```
Using version ^2.8 for zendframework/zend-cache
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-cache 2.8.2
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-cache 2.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-cache 2.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-cache 2.9.x-dev
    - Conclusion: remove zendframework/zend-eventmanager 3.1.0
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-cache ^2.8 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-cache[2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.9.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-eventmanager 3.1.0
    - zendframework/zend-cache 2.8.x-dev requires zendframework/zend-eventmanager ^2.6.3 || ^3.2 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-eventmanager[2.6.3, 2.6.4, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.3.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-eventmanager[2.6.3, 3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-eventmanager[2.6.4, 3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-eventmanager[3.2.0, 3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-eventmanager[3.2.1, 3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-eventmanager[3.3.x-dev, 3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-eventmanager[3.2.x-dev, 3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-eventmanager[2.6.x-dev, 3.1.0].
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-eventmanager (locked at 3.1.0) -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-eventmanager[3.1.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I'm using the tutorial as a base:
https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Zend_Skeleton_Application/Getting_Zend_Skeleton_Application.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, this occurs because of conflicting versions of packages

I recommend restarting the installation process, because your project is new, I think it is faster than resolving all conflicts.

First, clear the cache and data already installed:

```
rm -rf composer.lock vendor
php composer.phar clear
```

Restart installing the package with conflict problem

```
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-session
```

After install anothers packages. Eg:

```
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-cache
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-mvc
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-db
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-modulemanager
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-mvc
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-crypt
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-escaper
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-mail
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-paginator
```

In the following tutorial that is, I think that marked Y switch instead of N, in answer for minimal installation packages.

```
   Do you want a minimal install (no optional packages)? Y/n
n
```

But, the clear all data that solution your problem.